# How to add a model field to a django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an app where I have a bunch of users and each user has a watchlist of stocks. I know I can use a manytomany relationship to model this since each user will have multiple stocks and vice versa, but it gets really messy on the admin (since I have a list of stocks and I have to click on each one to find out which user(s) it belongs to).

```
class Stocks(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am wondering if there is any way I can set it up so that when I click on an individual user, I can see all the stocks they have on their watchlist. I was initially thinking there might be a way to add a field in the user model that contains all of their stocks.

Answer (score 0):

When you select a User's portfolio, you can see all the stocks held by this user. I dont really see why'd you want to use a 'manytomany' for users on your stocks model. Every user should have 1 Portfolio. And every Portfolio can have multiple stocks. Let me know if this works for you.

```
class Stocks(models.Model):      
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)    

class Portfolio(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    stock = models.ManyToManyField(Stocks)
```

Comment: I see what you are doing and it makes sense. But from what I understand your solution still does not offer a way to click on a user from the admin and see which portfolio(s) belongs to them? I would have to click on a portfolio and see which user it belongs to. Does this make sense?